# emacs `C-S-<mouse-1>` sequence

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am trying to bind the [multiple-cursors.el](https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el) click event, using the following line in my `.emacs` configuration file:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-<mouse-1>") 'mc/add-cursor-on-click)
```

I don't get this specific sequence of keys, here is what I am doing now :

- `C` => <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
- `S` => <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>s</kbd>
- `<mouse-1>` => mouse click (left? right?)

But when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> I am prompted with the search in the minibar.

How do I get this shortcut working ?

*Note* : in case this is relevant, I am using [emacs-prelude](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude).

**Edit** : I made it working with the following lines, but I am still curious about the meaning of the previous sequence.

```
(global-unset-key (kbd "M-<down-mouse-1>"))
(global-set-key (kbd "M-<mouse-1>") 'mc/add-cursor-on-click)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "S" you mentioned is spurious.

The `C-S-<mouse-1>` sequence is just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left click</kbd>.

The reason you were getting dropped into the minibuffer requesting search input is because by default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> is bound to `isearch-forward`.

---

Edit:  I may have misread what you were looking for.

If you actually want to use the sequence <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> followed by <kbd>Left click</kbd> then you have use the following mapping:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-s <down-mouse-1>") 'mc/add-cursor-on-click)
```

Thanks to @resueman below for pointing this out.

Comment: Thanks, I feel a bit stupid now. But then, how would one represent a capital `S` ?

Comment: @nha You could use `C-S-s <mouse-1>` or `C-S-s <C-S-mouse-1>`

Comment: As @resueman alludes to, you can use `C-s` for "Ctrl+s" and `C-S-s` for "Ctrl+S".